# Angular (8.x) not providing file upload progress

Tags: angular

This feels very straightforward, but for some reason I feel like there could be a bug.
I am trying to upload a file:

```js
    // ... prep work above here

    const request = new HttpRequest(
      'POST',
      '/uploadFile/',
      formData,
      {
        reportProgress: true,
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Accept', 'application/vnd.medchat+json;v=2.0'),
        observe: 'events',
      },
    );

    return this.http.request(request);
```

As you can see I'm not doing anything fancy. Per the Angular docs, defining your own HttpRequest and passing it as a singular argument to the `http.request` method is supposed to by default return a stream of HttpEvents. However, I only get one event: the complete event.

Here is my method that calls that:

```
    this.uploadService.uploadFileList(id, fileList)
      .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        console.log('event occurred', event);
        switch (event.type) {
          case HttpEventType.Sent: {
            console.log('Request start');
            break;
          }
          case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader: {
            console.log('Response header received');
            break;
          }
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress: {
            const progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
            console.log(`Uploaded: ${progress}%`);
            break;
          }
          case HttpEventType.Response: {
            console.log('Request completed', event.body);
            break;
          }
        }
      });
```

The file successfully uploads but I get no progress events. I've tried this with files up to 5mb in size, and even with throttling in both chrome and firefox. No go.

I'm wondering what I'm missing here, does anyone see any holes? It doesn't even get the start event. Only the `HttpEventType.Response` case gets called.

Comment: Running into the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes - it's actually a bug in the 8.x versions, upgrading is the only solution.

Comment: Thx! You are right, I got it working on 10.

Comment: This is good to know for certain because we haven't managed to upgrade yet hahaha

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
HttpEventType.DownloadProgress
```

event type

in your switch case.

Comment: It doesn't matter. That observable does not fire anything but a complete event. Note the console log at the beginning of the callback handler, which would fire for any event type regardless of what the switch statement does.